# Unable to read the following JSON object, gives undefined even though element exists

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, string

I have the following Object (after some dot operating inside)
I called it props.stuff , 
Given: data is passed from Parent component to child as

```
//Parent
componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  async getData() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "{link here}"
    );
    const { data } = await res;
    this.setState({ stuff: data});
  }

<Child props={this.state.stuff} />
```

so, in Child when I do `console.log(props.stuff)`:

```
props.stuff= {
"date":"November 14",
"status":"PENDING",
"id":"146859",
"invoice_number":"123685479624",
"amount":"950.00",
"currency":"$"
}
```

But trying to access props.stuff.date ( or anything like props.stuff.*{element}* ) gives me **undefined**.
What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** I got the string below by doing console.log(JSON.stringify(props.stuff)) so this is exactly what it is.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. Also note that [there is no such thing as a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation): either it is a JSON string or an object.

Answer (score -2):

So I figured out the solution finally. Actually props was being passed to a child component from a parent component and in the parent component, it was being fetched through an API call. So initial value of props was undefined.

In the parent component, writing:

```
{props.stuff && <Child stuff={props.stuff} />}
```

This made sure that props is passed only if it exists, hence fixing the issue

Comment: such basic mistake